# Suming values according to different criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to sum value in the same column but depending on certain creteria in different columns i.e.

```
value   column1 column2 column3
 11        a       x      m
 45        b       y      n
 50        b       z      p
 12        c       x      p
```

So e.g. I want the total sum for 'Value' when 
column1 = b & column2 = z & column n

I used the following syntax:

```
sum(case when column1 = b & column2 = z & column n then value end) total
```

which worked but I am dealing with lot of columns, so is there an easier way to do this.
I was thinking loops, but can't make sense of loops in SQL.

Comment: What you're doing there works; or you could move your condition to the where statement if you're only after one result.  There's no simple way to add lots of different conditions without explicitly adding the conditions unless there's some underlying rule which they obey.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(value) FROM table GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
```

and if needed for a specific set you can use

```
SELECT SUM(value) FROM table GROUP BY col1, col2, col3 HAVING col1='a' AND col2='n' AND col3='c'
```

Comment: Its a better method but I am afraid I still have to type all possible combinations between columns which is the biggest problem because I have many columns to deal with.

Comment: If you dont need to haing clause (because then you always need to set all vars to what you need them to be) you could create a stored procedure (mysql5+) to automatically create the query with a group on all columns